# Set Z-Index of Window comparatively to other windows

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

How can I, in VB.NET, set a window's z-index comparatively to other windows?

My program runs in the background of other programs, and when a specific event happens, my custom class pops up. However, sometimes, this window is in the background of other apps. How can I make it such that my window always comes to the front? I realize that there are questions like mine, but I cannot find any in *Visual Basic*.

I would really appreciate code in VB.NET, not C#.

Thanks,

Odinulf

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`TopMost` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) to `True`.